# How to select all data under a certain class in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I use `findAll`, with my class and my tag the code does not find anything
This is my try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get the data
data = requests.get('https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Counter-Strike%3A%20Global%20Offensive/clips?range=24hr/')

# load data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

clip = soup.find_all("a", ["tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit"])

print(clip)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: the webpage is dynamically generated. That means the page's javascript needs to be rendered for the elements, you are trying to find, to exist. This is a job for selenium/pyppeteer/requests-html

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded dynamically via Ajax, but you can use `requests`/`json` modules to load it:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://gql.twitch.tv/gql#origin=twilight'

params = [{"operationName":"ClipsCards__Game","variables":{"gameName":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","limit":20,"criteria":{"languages":[],"filter":"LAST_WEEK"}},"extensions":{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"0d8d0eba9fc7ef77de54a7d933998e21ad7a1274c867ec565ac14ffdce77b1f9"}}}]
headers = {'Client-Id': 'kimne78kx3ncx6brgo4mv6wki5h1ko'}

data =  requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for g in data[0]['data']['game']['clips']['edges']:
    print('{:<60} {:<10} {}'.format(g['node']['title'], g['node']['viewCount'], g['node']['url']))
```

Prints:

```
12 y/o ace                                                   121409     https://clips.twitch.tv/GoldenBlitheBillKeepo
Dupreeh feeling himself                                      51384      https://clips.twitch.tv/TenderBlatantCattleWoofer
ZyWoo Deagle Ace                                             49288      https://clips.twitch.tv/FurryWiseLemurLitty
ART + GAU JOGO DA TEAM ONE                                   34676      https://clips.twitch.tv/FamousDeliciousCasetteSMOrc
flusha insane 1v4                                            32522      https://clips.twitch.tv/NaiveSavoryLadiesOneHand
UNLUCKY XDD                                                  31698      https://clips.twitch.tv/AveragePoisedDelicataCmonBruh
lindinho clutchzero 1x3                                      24808      https://clips.twitch.tv/SmokyIronicMangetoutDatBoi
Stewie2k Selfless Play                                       24693      https://clips.twitch.tv/TallViscousSlothBloodTrail
bedzie magik flesh                                           20393      https://clips.twitch.tv/TangibleAverageDugongNononoCat
moe vs autimatic on stream                                   20311      https://clips.twitch.tv/CrowdedYummyNigiriPastaThat
Tarik insane 1v5 his first EU FPL game                       20104      https://clips.twitch.tv/HappyTangibleChowderRiPepperonis
Snax zaskakuje przeciwnika i wygrywa przegraną rundę!        19614      https://clips.twitch.tv/SpinelessFragileEchidnaImGlitch
Welcome to EU Tarik                                          18400      https://clips.twitch.tv/StormySavageDotterelYee
csgo'd                                                       17318      https://clips.twitch.tv/EmpathicAwkwardOtterHeyGuys
epic sauce                                                   15501      https://clips.twitch.tv/AttractiveRacyPhoneYouWHY
NiKo 1v2 2x 1taps                                            15088      https://clips.twitch.tv/SuspiciousJoyousSalsifyPogChamp
morda                                                        14394      https://clips.twitch.tv/PuzzledLightMonkeyMingLee
RAIN 3k vs sAw                                               14387      https://clips.twitch.tv/TastySavoryKangarooPRChase
Synchronous grenade throwing                                 13881      https://clips.twitch.tv/TransparentFrailCoffeePipeHype
sneaky fail ;p                                               13668      https://clips.twitch.tv/SquareRockyBunnyCclamChamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `selenium` instead of `requests` to get the website's html code. Here is how you do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Counter-Strike%3A%20Global%20Offensive/clips?range=24hr/')

time.sleep(5)

data = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

clip = soup.find_all("a", class_ = "tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit")

print(clip)
```

Output:

```
[<a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/natosaphix/clip/GoldenBlitheBillKeepo"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="12 y/o ace">12 y/o ace</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/dreamhackcs/clip/TenderBlatantCattleWoofer"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="Dupreeh feeling himself">Dupreeh feeling himself</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/dreamhackcs3/clip/FurryWiseLemurLitty"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="ZyWoo Deagle Ace">ZyWoo Deagle Ace</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/artcsgo/clip/FamousDeliciousCasetteSMOrc"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="ART + GAU JOGO DA TEAM ONE">ART + GAU JOGO DA TEAM ONE</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/dreamhackcs/clip/NaiveSavoryLadiesOneHand"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="flusha insane 1v4">flusha insane 1v4</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/pago3/clip/AveragePoisedDelicataCmonBruh"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="UNLUCKY XDD">UNLUCKY XDD</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/deercheerup/clip/SmokyIronicMangetoutDatBoi"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="lindinho clutchzero 1x3">lindinho clutchzero 1x3</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/esl_csgo/clip/TallViscousSlothBloodTrail"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="Stewie2k Selfless Play">Stewie2k Selfless Play</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/pago3/clip/TangibleAverageDugongNononoCat"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="bedzie magik flesh">bedzie magik flesh</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/tarik/clip/CrowdedYummyNigiriPastaThat"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="moe vs autimatic on stream">moe vs autimatic on stream</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/tarik/clip/HappyTangibleChowderRiPepperonis"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="Tarik insane 1v5 his first EU FPL game">Tarik insane 1v5 his first EU FPL game</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/tebtv/clip/SpinelessFragileEchidnaImGlitch"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="Snax zaskakuje przeciwnika i wygrywa przegraną rundę!">Snax zaskakuje przeciwnika i wygrywa przegraną rundę!</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/snax/clip/UninterestedPoisedBadgerNononoCat"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="snax o neo i tazie">snax o neo i tazie</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/niko/clip/StormySavageDotterelYee"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="Welcome to EU Tarik">Welcome to EU Tarik</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/esl_csgo/clip/EmpathicAwkwardOtterHeyGuys"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="csgo'd">csgo'd</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/dextersjourney/clip/AttractiveRacyPhoneYouWHY"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="epic sauce">epic sauce</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/dreamhackcs2/clip/SuspiciousJoyousSalsifyPogChamp"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="NiKo 1v2 2x 1taps">NiKo 1v2 2x 1taps</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/innocenttt/clip/PuzzledLightMonkeyMingLee"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="morda">morda</h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/dreamhackcs2/clip/TastySavoryKangarooPRChase"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="RAIN 3k vs sAw ">RAIN 3k vs sAw </h3></div></a>, <a class="tw-full-width tw-interactive tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-link--inherit" href="/csgomc_ru/clip/TransparentFrailCoffeePipeHype"><div class="tw-align-items-start tw-flex"><h3 class="tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-5" title="Synchronous grenade throwing">Synchronous grenade throwing</h3></div></a>]
```

I think that you are trying to scrape the video link and the title from these `anchor` tags. In order to do this, add these lines to your code:

```
for a in clip:
    print('-'*100)
    print(f"Title = {a.div.h3['title']}")
    print(f"Link = https://www.twitch.tv/{a['href']}")
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = 12 y/o ace
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//natosaphix/clip/GoldenBlitheBillKeepo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Dupreeh feeling himself
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//dreamhackcs/clip/TenderBlatantCattleWoofer
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = ZyWoo Deagle Ace
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//dreamhackcs3/clip/FurryWiseLemurLitty
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = ART + GAU JOGO DA TEAM ONE
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//artcsgo/clip/FamousDeliciousCasetteSMOrc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = flusha insane 1v4
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//dreamhackcs/clip/NaiveSavoryLadiesOneHand
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = UNLUCKY XDD
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//pago3/clip/AveragePoisedDelicataCmonBruh
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = lindinho clutchzero 1x3
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//deercheerup/clip/SmokyIronicMangetoutDatBoi
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Stewie2k Selfless Play
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//esl_csgo/clip/TallViscousSlothBloodTrail
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = bedzie magik flesh
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//pago3/clip/TangibleAverageDugongNononoCat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = moe vs autimatic on stream
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//tarik/clip/CrowdedYummyNigiriPastaThat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Tarik insane 1v5 his first EU FPL game
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//tarik/clip/HappyTangibleChowderRiPepperonis
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Snax zaskakuje przeciwnika i wygrywa przegraną rundę!
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//tebtv/clip/SpinelessFragileEchidnaImGlitch
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Welcome to EU Tarik
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//niko/clip/StormySavageDotterelYee
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = csgo'd
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//esl_csgo/clip/EmpathicAwkwardOtterHeyGuys
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = epic sauce
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//dextersjourney/clip/AttractiveRacyPhoneYouWHY
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = NiKo 1v2 2x 1taps
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//dreamhackcs2/clip/SuspiciousJoyousSalsifyPogChamp
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = morda
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//innocenttt/clip/PuzzledLightMonkeyMingLee
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = RAIN 3k vs sAw 
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//dreamhackcs2/clip/TastySavoryKangarooPRChase
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Synchronous grenade throwing
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//csgomc_ru/clip/TransparentFrailCoffeePipeHype
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = sneaky fail ;p 
Link = https://www.twitch.tv//pashabiceps/clip/SquareRockyBunnyCclamChamp
```

Comment: what's the point in using `bs4` if you're gonna be using selenium anyway? selenium already has element finding methods. use those instead

Comment: I always use ```selenium``` to interact with the website and ```BeautifulSoup``` to parse the website. This is because ```selenium``` is very good at interacting with elements and ```BeautifulSoup``` is very good at parsing the html code.

Comment: what? selenium has the same parsing capabilities as beautifulsoup, if not more. It's a full on browser driver afterall. Using both seems wasteful

Comment: Yeah I know that. But this is how I prefer doing it.